# list picker selection issue in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listpicker

```
List<CLASS> list = new List<CLASS>();

        list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
                   select new CLASS
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
                       Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                       title = query.Element("title").Value
                   }).ToList();

        listPicker2.DataContext = list;
```

How do I display list picker selected item in list picker in windows phone,
I have binded list picker in page load event, but every time I select item of list picker items, within an second it automatically selects the first item,
how to solve this?

Comment: post some code where you are binding your list picker

Comment: @Pradeep in page load event, listPicker.DataContext = list

Comment: Post your code.............

Comment: assigning it in page load event is a necessity?

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal yes..because, i have binded another listpicker in onnavigatedto event.So

Comment: this one can also be binded on the same event. You can bind two listpickers in one event. That should not create any problem.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal give me other way bro..please

Comment: check the answer(trick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok one trick could be like this

take a global int variable on the top of the page

```
int refreshCount=0;
```

after the list gets filled, assign this refreshCount to some int value say 1

```
    List<CLASS> list = new List<CLASS>();

    list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
               select new CLASS
               {
                   Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
                   Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                   title = query.Element("title").Value
               }).ToList();

    listPicker2.DataContext = list;
    refreshCount=1;
```

Now enclose this complete block with a simple condition and your code would become like this

```
if(refreshCount==0)
{
        List<CLASS> list = new List<CLASS>();
        list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
                   select new CLASS
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
                       Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                       title = query.Element("title").Value
                   }).ToList();

        listPicker2.DataContext = list;
        refreshCount=1;
}
```

By this you should get rid of your problems.

Comment: :) though It is is not the perfect possible way.